# PCB stackup ambigous percent number

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, pcb-layers

In this stack-up what are those presented in right-side of picture?
[image]

update:

The person who respond from manufacturer told me that is "residual copper ratio". But I think she is misunderstood because there is nothing about it on the web!
This is from PCBway, and I think it is maybe 4350B since I have other 6layer stackup like in the picture attached, that they have written 4350B next to it's (Roger layer) percent number.

Update regarding to Elmesito's answer:
[image]
Can your theory (%s are the compressing ratio of thicknesses) explain this other stack-up and "residual copper ratio"in last paragraph?

Comment: Does it have a title line?

Comment: Looks a like an academic published table not a PCB Fab dwg or stackup readme file.  Rogers makes dozens of different PTFE's, FR4's and Ceramic.. I suspect the L refers to 4 conductive layers and who knows what the % means

Comment: If the context does not discuss it, what are the specs? =tbd

Comment: Any idea **which** Rogers material they're talking about?

Comment: I agree , the vague use of the Brand name without a part number makes the % number meaningless. maybe its the speed of light %c due to e.

Comment: @EugeneSh. no. :(

Comment: @ThePhoton This is from PCBway, and I think it is maybe 4350B since I have other 6layer stackup that they have written 4350B next to it's percent.

Answer (score 3):

The percentage shown is most likely the thickness left over once the PCB is pressed.

Rogers is a ceramic material, which doesn't shrink however the resin that sticks the layers together does. That also explains why FR4, a woven and resin filled material shrinks more compared to Rogers.

It is strange, however, that the two 1080 prepregs that are in the middle, which have an initial thickness of 75 micron each, and a final thickness of 70 micron each once pressed, have not been specified as percentage. Maybe the shrinkage is already included in the figures listed for the outer layers.

Comment: Rogers also uses FR4, glass and PTFE. I suspect this is PTFE|PP|FR4

Comment: Another possibility is it's the resin content if this is an epoxy-fiberglass material. That number can be used as an input to working out the geometry for controlled impedance lines.

Comment: Can "residual copper ratio" in the updated part of question, help understand  the question better? or are you sure?

Comment: Question update according to your answer

Answer (score 1):

Residual copper ratio is how much copper needs to be left on that layer to maintain the specified thickness, after all traces have been etched.  If you have a lot of bare area then the thickness won't be maintained.  You should fill those areas with ground plane, hatch, or other pattern.

Comment: I think your answer is very helpful. I wonder if you could perhaps add a link to some further source of information as well.